# jQuery UI dialog not responding properly to Delete click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-dialog

I am brand-new to jQuery and trying to implement a jQuery UI dialog on a Gridview item by following this article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238122/Delete-Functionality-in-GridView-with-Confirmation

I've stepped through this code using the Chrome Dev Tool and the dialog displays properly but when I click the Delete button, the associated anonymous function __doPostBack(uniqueID does not appear to fire. Can a JS breakpoint be set to trap a click of "Delete" button on the client side? For the server-side code, I've got a breakpoint in Visual Studio where the postback would normally be entered but its never hit.

Here is the relevant column of my ASP.Net Gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deleting..">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <!--To fire the OnRowDeleting event.-->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
            OnClientClick="return deleteItem(this);"
            ControlStyle-CssClass="buttonInRow"  
            Text="Delete">
        </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is how it renders:

```
<td>
        <!--To fire the OnRowDeleting event.-->
        <a onclick="return deleteItem(this);" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_GridView1_ctl02_lbDelete" class="buttonInRow" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$GridView1$ctl02$lbDelete','')">Delete</a>
        </td>
```

I get no errors on the following scripts:

```
$(function() {
    InitializeDeleteConfirmation();
});

function InitializeDeleteConfirmation() {
$('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Delete": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
}
function deleteItem(element) {
var uniqueID = element.id;
var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
// Cells[n]: n referring to the cell number displayed on GridView; n starting from 0...
var PositionTitle = row.cells[0].innerText;
    var dialogTitle = 'Permanently Delete Item: ' + PositionTitle + '?';

    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").html('<p><span class="ui-icon " + "ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>" + "Please click delete to confirm deletion.</p>');

    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").dialog({
        title: dialogTitle,
        buttons: {
        "Delete": function () { __doPostBack(uniqueID, ''); 
                  $(this).dialog("close"); },
        "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
     });

    $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog('open');  
    return false;
```

}

The idea here is that **deleteItem** script above always returns **false** because (ostensibly) it handles the postback just before closing the dialog (i.e. same code as on the rendered HTML snippet above). Could this __doPostBack function be failing on me and not breaking in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I will try to explain to help someone else in the future. The principle here is that the jQuery dialog is going to do the __doPostBack function directly from Javascript. The key to the problem is shown in the rendered snippet above also pasted here:

```
<a onclick="return deleteItem(this);" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_GridView1_ctl02_lbDelete" class="buttonInRow"    href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$GridView1$ctl02$lbDelete','')">Delete</a>
```

Note the difference in values between ID and the first argument to doPostBack:

```
id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_GridView1_ctl02_lbDelete"
```

versus

```
  ('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$GridView1$ctl02$lbDelete'
```

So, I changed my script to create a "postbackID" from the "uniqueID" as follows:

```
function deleteItem(element) {
var uniqueID = element.id;
var postbackID = uniqueID.split("_").join("$");
var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
var PositionTitle = row.cells[0].innerText; 
    var dialogTitle = 'Permanently Delete Item: ' + PositionTitle + '?';
    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").html('<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>" + "Please click delete to confirm deletion.</p>');
    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").dialog({
        title: dialogTitle,
        buttons: {
        "Delete": function() {
            __doPostBack(postbackID, ''); 
            $(this).dialog("close"); },
        "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
});
$('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog('open');
return false;
```

}

There are probably more elegant ways to do this but I am thrilled to have successfully implemented the promised results in the great paper on **CodeProject** by ***junnark***. For example, he retrieves **this.name** and uses that for direct invocation of __doPostBack. I tried adding the name attribute to my asp:LinkButton but it renders with the "short name" only rather than the full naming container name(s). In his article, he is using an ImageButton while I am using a LinkButton control so that probably is the root of that difference.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very confusing and difficult to follow.  For .NET rendered controls I always suggest looking at the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Then your code simplifies to this:

```
$('[id$="lbDelete"]').on('click', function(e) {
  // Your link element available as a jQuery object
  var $el = $(this);

  // Prevent the link from firing before anything else can happen
  e.preventDefault();

  // Now you can manipulate the DOM using your link as a reference point
  // eg. $el.parent()...
});
```

Also you can put a breakpoint within this function to debug line-by-line.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the feedback. Like I said, I am a rookie. At the top of my post is a link to the article upon which this is based and my client-side code is identical to that in the article. Your approach is interesting but not necessary. I have breakpoints elsewhere and can debug "line by line" but a specific question in the OP is how to set a breakpoint inside the function assigned to the DELETE button: "Delete": function () { __doPostBack(uniqueID, ''); 
                  $(this).dialog("close"); },                                 Can you help on that part of the question?

Comment: How stupid of me to ask how to set breakpoint on the __doPostBack function! I simply broke the above object notation into a new separate line for the __doPostBack and Chrome debugger stopped there at my breakpoint. Duh! I went on to verify the successful passage through that function (with the proper unique elementID). Debugging for me now shifts back to focus on webforms page life-cycle madness on the server.